Existance of tubular neighborhood

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact oriented hypersurface of class $C^k$, $k\geq 2$. There is a neighborhood $V$  of $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a number $\varepsilon >0$ such that the map $F(x,t) = x+t\nu(x)$ is a $C^{k-1}$ diffeomorphism of $S\times(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ onto $V$.

This statement and a "proof" can be found in Introduction to PDEs by Folland.  I am looking for a more rigorous proof of this statement. Here is what I tried so far.
$F$ is $C^{k-1}$ since $\nu$ is. For $x\in S$ we want to look at the Jacobian of $F$ (w.r.t. local coordinates) at $(x,0)$ so we define a local parameterisation. There exist open sets $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, $x\in W\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a function $\psi\in C^k(U;\mathbb{R})$ so that $\psi: U\rightarrow S\cap W$ is bijective and has a continuous inverse. Local coordinates of $x$ are thus given by $u_0 = \psi^{-1}(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Next we set $$G(u,t) = F(\psi(u),t)$$ for $u\in U$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Clearly $G^{\prime}(u_0,0)$ is nonsingular since the first $n-1$ columns of $G'(u_0,0)$ consist of vectors that span the tangent space of $S$ at $x$ and the last column is just $\nu(\psi(u_0)) = \nu(x)$ which is orthogonal to said tangent space.
We now want to apply the inverse mapping theorem. It states that we can find open neighborhoods $(U_x\times I_x) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}$ containing $(u_0,0)$ and $W_x$ containing $G(u_0,0) = x$ such that $G: U_x \times I_x \rightarrow W_x$ is a $C^{k-1}$ diffeomorphism. Hence $$F_x^{-1}: W_x \rightarrow \psi(U_x)\times I_x$$ is a $C^{k-1}$ inverse of $F$ (locally near $x$). I don't really know where to go from here as it is just a bit different of what's done in the "proof". For reference:

Hence by the inverse mapping theorem $F$ can be inverted on a neighborhood $W_x$ of each $(x_0,0)$ to yield a $C^{k-1}$ diffeomorphism $$ F_x^{-1}: W_x \rightarrow (S\cap W_x) \times(-\varepsilon_x,\varepsilon_x)  $$ for some $\varepsilon_x>0$.

What I don't understand is why $F_x^{-1}$ maps to $(S\cap W_x)\times(-\varepsilon_x,\varepsilon_x)$. Specifically, where does this interval come from, why is is symmetric around $0$? Why do I only get these sets $I_x$ and $U_x$?
I kind of understand the next steps of the proof. By compactness you can choose $(x_n)_n\subset S$ such that $W_{x_n}$ cover $S$ and you somehow patch $F_{x_n}^{-1}$ together to receive a $C^{k-1}$ inverse of $F$.

You restrict to the preimage of such a symmetric interval.

So I need to find an interval $(-\varepsilon_x, \varepsilon_x)\subset I_x$ and a $\tilde{W_x}\subset W_x$ such that $F_x^{-1}:\tilde{W_x} \rightarrow (S\cap \tilde{W_x})\times (-\varepsilon_x,\varepsilon_x)$ is still a $C^{k-1}$ diffeomorphism? How do I know that such $\varepsilon_x$ and $\tilde{W_x}$ exist?

It seems like I can just chose any interval $(-\varepsilon_x,\varepsilon_x)\subset I_x$ and set $\tilde{W_x} = F(\psi(U_x)\times(-\varepsilon_x,\varepsilon_x))$. Then for $y\in \tilde{W_x}$ we have $y = F(x,t)$ for $(x,t)\in \psi(U_x)\times(-\varepsilon_x,\varepsilon_x)$ and since $x = F(x,0)$, $x$ is in $\tilde{W_x}$ and so $F^{-1}$ really does map from $\tilde{W_x}$ to $(S\cap \tilde{W_x})\times(-\varepsilon_x,\varepsilon_x)$. Thanks a lot.
